# Laplace transform integral - calculus question

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

In order to find a mapping from $t$ to $s$ in Laplace transform, we do the following:

$$\mathcal{L}(F(t)) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}F(t)\,dt$$

In order to explain this question better - say we want to find a laplace transorm of $F(t) = t$. We use integration by parts:

$$\mathcal{L}(F(t)) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}t \, dt = \left.-\frac{1}{s} e^{-st} t \right|_0^\infty - \frac{1}{s}\int_0^\infty e^{-st} \, dt$$

Now, in my book (Phil Dyke, intro to Laplace transforms and Fourier series) it is assumed that: $e^{-st}t\Big|_0^\infty = 0$. Therefore, it says that $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty}e^{-st} = 0$.

Why is that? There is no where mentioned in my book that $s > 0$ in Laplace transform. I cannot understand why the above is assumed, and what is even $s$? If it is just another variable, is it complex/real, does it have to be only positive? If it is complex, what does it even mean if the limit in $t \rightarrow \infty$? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: These integrals make no sense unless  $\Re(s) < 0$.

Comment: Is $s$ complex then? Well, the textbook i mentioned uses these integrals everywhere to prove everything connected to laplace transforms in first 2 chapters.

Comment: $s$ can be conplex, but it does not have to be.

Comment: So, then s > 0, or it does not converge

Comment: The resultant value of the Laplace Transform when $\Re(s)$ is assumed to be greater than $0$ can be used to assign values for $\Re(s)\le 0$ kind of how a geometric series does not converge for $|s|\ge 1$ but the function $\frac{1}{1-s}$ can be used to give values for the series.

Comment: Assume that the Laplace transform is defined wherever the integral makes sense, and that it extends into the complex plane for $s$ if you want it to. There are good reasons to allow $s$ to be defined in the complex plane that are not evident at first, and definitely not evident until you have studied some Complex Analysis.